# R Shiny UI Move InfoBox

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Is there any way to justify the blue box (including icon)?

[image: Move this Blue box]

This doesn't seem to accept a style argument. Ideally, the title would be over the blue box with the dynamic value inside it.

```
output$BOX<- shinydashboard::renderInfoBox({
  infoBox(
    title = "Percent BNPX",
    icon = icon("fa-solid fa-laptop-file"),
    value = perc_muc(),
    width = boxwidth,
    color = "blue",
    fill  = booleanfill
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation of the function from rdoumentation.org

```
infoBox(title, 
value = NULL, 
subtitle = NULL, 
icon = shiny::icon("bar-chart"), 
color = "aqua", 
width = 4, href = NULL, 
fill = FALSE)
```

We have the ‘width’ variable, and shiny is natively using Bootstrap and Bootstrap divides the page into 12 vertical grids. So, 12/4 = 3 vertical grids.

Messing with the ‘width’ variable will get you the size you want.